# How to select 2G as data network on iOS 8?

Tags: ios

It is stated on the iOS 8.1 release notes that users can now select 2G, 3G or 4G LTE as their data network.

I've since updated to iOS 8.1 but I could not find where the option is to select 2G data network.

Where can I find this setting option?

Comment: I have Verizon Wireless (USA) CDMA-EvDO 3G service. I have a iPhone 6 running iOS 8.1, and I do not have the option to switch to the "2G" service, only LTE and 3G. As most people, I like to preserve my iPhone's battery life, so I would like to switch it to 2G, but for now it looks impossible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be found in `Settings > Cellular > Voice & Data` where in the option is available to select between 2G,3G and LTE.

[image]

If the voice option is not available for your iPhone. Please call and check with your respective service/carrier provider.

It's been noted that some of the carrier update for the iOS 8 has removed the "Voice & Data" option because Apple let the carriers to update the cellular settings. It's only a matter of reverting back the update from the service/carrier providers.