# How to turn 3G off on iPhone 5 running iOS8?

Tags: iphone, ios

After the update to iOS8, the switch to disable the 3G has been replaced by a disable 4G switch.

4G is already off but how could I also disable also 3G (which is still active, as shown on the status bar)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select 2G as data network on iOS 8?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152419/how-to-select-2g-as-data-network-on-ios-8)

Answer (score 1):

Settings->Cellular->Voice&Data: choose 2G

Comment: Since the full switching was re-introduced in [I think] iOS 8.3, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can only really turn off "all" mobile data, so there's no falling back on good old GPRS...

If you go to:

```
Settings -> Mobile -> Mobile Data (and 4G if you want that off too).
```

"Mobile Data" is the old "3G" switch, I guess. I suppose apple assume that the entire world is 3G ready xD

It will disable all data via mobile (not wifi etc..)...

Comment: Apple does not assume. It's handled by the carriers.

Comment: I meant apple in general :).. pedantics though..

Comment: Just to clarify. What I meant is that the newer versions of IOS don't make any utterance of GPRS any more. It's ac case go 3G or no mobile internet :D

Comment: My phone will auto-drop to GPRS, or Edge, if I can't get 3G or 4G. Worst cases it shows no 'type' at all.